# What is the recipe which adds /etc/hosts file to the yocto-base Linux distribution?

Tags: yocto

I'm developing a Yocto distribution and I need to substitute the default file `/etc/hosts` by a new `hosts` file where I have to insert some DNS settings.

The default file which I have found in the image is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

To modify the file `/etc/hosts` in the Yocto image I need to find the recipe which adds the file to image. Someone can help me to find this recipe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question myself. I don't know if this is the best solution, but for me it is enough.

I can divide the task in two different steps.

### First step: find the recipe

I'm working with the **Zeus** release of yocto; in this release I've eventually found the recipe that installs `/etc/hosts` in the image; the recipe is:
`meta/recipes-core/base-fles/base-files_<recipe_version>.bb`

To find previous recipe I looked for the file `hosts` into the folder which contains all the yocto layers. To do that I have executed the following commands:

```
cd <path/to/yocto/folder>
find ./meta* -name "*hosts*"
```

The output of the previous command contains:

```
...
./meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/hosts
...
```

Inside the recipe `./meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb` I have found the following assignement:

```
SRC_URI = "file://rotation \
           file://nsswitch.conf \
           file://motd \
=========> file://hosts \
           file://host.conf \
           file://profile \
           file://shells \
           file://fstab \
           file://issue.net \
           file://issue \
           file://share/dot.bashrc \
           file://share/dot.profile \
           file://licenses/GPL-2 \
           "
```

where is present the `hosts` file.

### Second step: create a `base_files_%.bbappend` file

The way I have found to substitute the `hosts` file is by adding a `base_files_%.bbappend` file (in `mylayer/recipes-core/base-files`) and substitute the default `hosts` file with my new `hosts` file.

The content of my file `base_files_%.bbappend` is:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/base-files:"

SRC_URI = "file://rotation \
       file://nsswitch.conf \
       file://motd \
       file://hosts \
       file://host.conf \
       file://profile \
       file://shells \
       file://fstab \
       file://issue.net \
       file://issue \
       file://share/dot.bashrc \
       file://share/dot.profile \
       file://licenses/GPL-2 \
"
```

Furthermore I have inserted the new `hosts` file inside the folder:
`mylayer/recipes-core/base-fles/base-files`:

```
mylayer
   |
   recipes-core
      |
      base-files
         |
         base-files
            |
            hosts
```

The other files listed in the `SRC_URI` definition (`rotation`, `nsswitch.conf`, and so on) continue to come from the main `base-files` folder that is:
`meta/recipes-core/base-fles/base-files`.

Comment: Would it make more sense to implement a do_install_append() function in your bbappend file to copy just the hosts file over?

Comment: Thanks, may be you are right, but at the moment I can't test your suggestion. When I will go back to my yocto project I'll try to use `do_install_append()` function. I'm not very expert on yocto so the solution that I found works, but I don't know if it is the best solution. Thanks again.